# React hooks set functions not working from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've a `isView` and `setIsView` in the `ParentComponent` and passing them down to the `ChildComponent` as `props` and trying to do show/hide conditional rendering but `setIsView` seems not to be working and `isView` value in the props remains same.

```
const ParentComponent = props => {
    const [isView, setIsView] = useState(true);

    const onChange = selectedOption => {
        selectedOption === 'Report'
            ? setIsView(true)
            : setIsView(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
          <ChildComponent
             isView={isView} 
             onChange={onChange}
           />
        </div>
    );
};

const ChildComponent = props => {
    const {isView, onChange} = props;

    return (
        <div>
          <RadioButton 
             onChange={() => onChange('Not-Report')}
           />

           <If condition={isView}>
               <ChildComponent2>
           </If>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Edit: changed `onChange={onChange('Not-Report')}` to `onChange={() => onChange('Not-Report')}` as suggested by some. still not working.

Comment: try this in child component `<RadioButton  onChange={() => onChange('Not-Report')}/>`, i added answer with the description

Comment: after changing to callback function I can see the execution goes to onChange method on ParentComponent but value is not updating

Answer (score 1):

Try feeding the onChange method as a callback function instead.

```
const ChildComponent = props => {
    const {isView, onChange} = props;

    return (
        <div>
          <RadioButton 
             onChange={() => onChange('Not-Report')} // <- Here
           />

           <If condition={isView}>
               <ChildComponent2>
           </If>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: That should've worked, I wonder if it's the name of the function that's causing that issue. Can you rename that method to something like `onChangeHandler`

Comment: RadioButton seems like a custom component, is that from a framework? If not, can we take a look at that? The only other thing that i can think of is the onChange function is probably not being passed into that component.

Comment: Yes It's a private npm component, it works fine and the call goes to parent's onChange I can confirm

Comment: Tried the exact code on codesandbox, it works as expected. The only difference is the RadioButton https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-surf-luqp6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Update child component onChange function as follows:

```
<RadioButton 
  onChange={() => onChange('Not-Report')}
/>
```

If you pass onChange only, it will be regarded with the function that has `event` as a parameter rather than the prop's onChange function.

---

To make it work like your way,

```
const ChildComponent = ({isView, onChange}) => {
    const onRadioChange = () => {
       onChange('Not-Report')}
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <RadioButton 
             onChange={onRadioChange}
           />

           <If condition={isView}>
               <ChildComponent2>
           </If>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Passing onChange as callback not working unfortunately :(

Comment: can you confirm if the parent's onChange is called when you click radio button of the child component?

Comment: Yep I can see the call goes to parent component onChange.

Comment: can you specify <If condition={isView}><ChildComponent2>   </If> in detail?

Comment: Yes It's a private npm component, works fine, it's just the value of isView is still true in the props which should ideally be false after clicking on RadioButton

Comment: can you try with this? <If condition={props.isView}>

Answer (score 0):

i am wrote this code
`ParentComponent`

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
  const [isView, setIsView] = useState(true);

  const onChange = (selectedOption) => {
    console.log("selectedOption = ", selectedOption);
    selectedOption === "Report" ? setIsView(true) : setIsView(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent isView={isView} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`ChildComponent`

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const { isView, onChange } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        checked={isView}
        onClick={() => {
          onChange("Not-Report");
        }}
      />
      isView = {isView ? "true" : "false"}
    </div>
  );
};
```

i change `onChange` to `onClick` and use `checked`

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]